# Show thingsboard device attribute latest value on customized control widget dashboard on thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I'm using thingsboard V1.3.1.Now i'm working on customized control widget on thingsboard.I received values in thingsboard device attributes. I want dynamic on and off button by passing 1 and 0 values.But my problem is how to show this latest values on my customized created on/off switch control widget on thingsboard dashboard.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,

Viswa

Answer (score 1):

You can set the parameters you wanna pass into the widget by configuring it in here first !

[image: Passing Parameter]

1. `attributeService = $scope.$injector.get('attributeService');` inside `self.onIni` function, this will get the Attributes you just set on the widget datasource.
2. After this, you gotta recover this info inside the widget. I would suggest you to do this into the `self.onDataUpdated` function (thingsboard uses AngularJS) so the button will update with the value.

```
self.onDataUpdated = function () {
        for (let i=0;i<subscription.data.length;i++) {
            let attributeValue = subscription.data[i].data[0][1];
            let dataKey = subscription.data[i].dataKey.name;
            if (dataKey === 'active') {
                $scope.activeVal = (attributeValue === 'true');
            }
        }
    };
```

The is here constantly going thru every single attribute, checking if the name matches with 'active', if yes, $scope attribute activeVal = active values you passed to the widget.

Thank it.